# SQLiteException: near ";" syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO SubjectsDB('softskill','no');

Tags: android

```
boolean DBExist = checkDatabaseExist();
Toast.makeText(this,DBExist + " <- DB Exists :p",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if(!DBExist){
SQLiteDatabase DB = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
try{
    DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SubjectsDB(name VARCHAR, major VARCHAR);");
    DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO SubjectsDB(\'softskill\',\'no\');");
}catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Ohh!!"+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
Toast.makeText(this,"Data Entered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This is the code where i am trying to insert the two strings into the database but it gives error at semicolon

Comment: DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO SubjectsDB values(\'softskill\',\'no\');");

Comment: thanks!! It works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

`DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO SubjectsDB values(\'softskill\',\'no\');");`